# How to remove padding in floating windows in Gnome?

Tags: gnome

System
Linux: Wayland, Gnome44 and Fedora38

---

I just discover there is air gap between windows of application at the right edge and bottom edge in float mode, if the window is resize by win+arrow, then there is no gap.

How can I fill the gap when float window? I found Emacs Gui have the same issue, but I can solve it by add (setq frame-resize-pixelwise t) in init.el.

Example: Gvim :(cannot drag the bottom more)
[image]

Example: Gnome Terminal :(cannot drag the bottom more)
[image]

Example: Vscode: (cannot drag the bottom more, and the gap is smaller than others)
[image]

I don't know if this is related to gnome window manager or the application itself?
It would be appreciate if you can provide solution, because sometimes I click the edge, it will accidentally activate windows behind.